# Blog tool which allow drag and drop from desktop image directly into blog

Tags: blogs

I'm not sure SO is the right place to ask this, but I'm willing to risk some downvotes for the answer because it would be enormously helpful. I've been using Google's "Blogger" tool, but unfortunately it has a rather cumbersome process for inserting images. Is there a blogging tool that just lets you drag an image from your destop directly into blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress apparently has this feature, see:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages